# WinUi3 Application().Current().Exit() Crash

Tags: uwp, winui-3, c++-winrt

I'm trying to exit a simple WinUI3 application when pressing a button:

```
void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application().Current().Exit();
}
```

When pressing the button I get the following error:
Any idea why and what would be the solution?

```
    KernelBase.dll!00007ff997994ffc()   Unknown
    [External Code] 
>   Example.exe!winrt::throw_hresult(const winrt::hresult result) Line 5016 C++
    Example.exe!winrt::check_hresult(const winrt::hresult result) Line 5087 C++
    Example.exe!winrt::impl::consume_Microsoft_UI_Xaml_IApplicationFactory<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationFactory>::CreateInstance(const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable & baseInterface, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable & innerInterface) Line 144 C++
    Example.exe!winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::{ctor}::__l2::<lambda>(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationFactory & f) Line 12262   C++
    Example.exe!winrt::impl::call_factory<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application,winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationFactory,winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application <lambda>(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationFactory &)>(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::{ctor}::__l2::winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application <lambda>(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationFactory &) && callback) Line 6397    C++
    Example.exe!winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::Application() Line 12262   C++
    Example.exe!winrt::Example::implementation::MainWindow::myButton_Click(const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable & __formal, const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs & __formal) Line 35 C++
    [External Code] 
    Example.exe!winrt::impl::delegate<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventHandler,void <lambda>(const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable &, const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs &)>::Invoke(void * sender, void * e) Line 4838   C++
    [External Code] 
    Example.exe!winrt::impl::consume_Microsoft_UI_Xaml_IApplicationStatics<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics>::Start(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::ApplicationInitializationCallback & callback) Line 158 C++
    Example.exe!winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::Start::__l2::<lambda>(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics & f) Line 12270    C++
    Example.exe!winrt::impl::factory_cache_entry<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application,winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics>::call<void <lambda>(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics &) &>(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::Start::__l2::void <lambda>(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics &) & callback) Line 6379    C++
    Example.exe!winrt::impl::call_factory<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application,winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics,void <lambda>(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics &)>(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::Start::__l2::void <lambda>(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics &) && callback) Line 6402   C++
    Example.exe!winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::Start(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::ApplicationInitializationCallback & callback) Line 12271   C++
    [External Code]
```

Comment: `Application()` invokes the constructor, but you intended to get a static class member instead, i.e., `Application::Current()`.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Post it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is indeed in the code provided. Here is an annotated version:

```cpp
void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application().Current().Exit();
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                  namespace
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^     type name
//                                         ^^   c'tor call
}
```

This tries to invoke the `Application` c'tor. However, `Application` is a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), and the `CreateInstace()` call on the factory object eventually fails since the application already exists.

This wasn't the goal of the code, though. Its author intended to access the `Application` object for the current application. This is exposed as the static [`Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.application.current) property. C++/WinRT models this as a static class member on the `Application` type, `Application::Current()`.

Following is the fixed version:

```cpp
void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::Current().Exit();
}
```